# Is there a name for this grammatical structure where a verb is followed by a direction?

Tags: etymology, phrases, verbs

In English there are lots of phrases where a verb is followed by a direction and it takes on a whole new meaning.

Examples: get up, get off, get down, take in, take out, take off, etc.

This is interesting to me because a lot of these expressions don't seem to make logical sense when you look at the meaning of each word. I.e. how did "take off" come to describe a plane departing?

Is there a name for this construction that I can look up? Do many other languages have similar constructions? Is there any known history of how this construction developed?

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: Such constructions are usually termed as phrasal verbs.

Comment: @use307254 'Phrasal verb" -- a misnomer if ever there was one!

Comment: According to Oxford Dictionary: Phrasal verb is 'An idiomatic phrase consisting of a verb and another element, typically either an adverb, as in break down, or a preposition, for example see to, or a combination of both, such as look down on.'